# Imported files not found

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project which runs on other machine(s). I get a compiler error importing a header "File not found".

The main project has a lot of nested folders. One of it's folders is a library. The header file with the problem is in the library.

So the path to the header, starting at the library project is basically:

libproject/header.h

And the path to the imported header is:

libproject/A/B/C/otherheader.h

This is how currently header imports otherheader:

`#import <libproject/otherheader.h>`

If I change this to

`#import <libproject/A/B/C/otherheader.h>`

It works, but this is used a lot of times everywhere, and I think the correct solution is to set somewhere a build path or something. The project works like this on other computers. But I'm an iOS beginner and have no idea what I have to do.

Can somebody help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: have u added that path to the header search path in your project settings?

Comment: But there are like 20 folders, and each of these contains a header file. Do I have to add an entry for all? I tried to put the path of the project with "recursive" there but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help find the problem, look at the actually build statement (last icon, the comment looking one), you will see the command line statement used to compile the file in this display (click on the icon to the right of the line for the full text). See if there are references to the folder containing the file. Usually this will give you a clue as to where clang is looking. Usually I copy the whole thing into an editor and replace ' -' with a return character so I can read it easier. Look for the -I lines

Comment: I found that the setup was a fairly complex thing and needed a lot of custom configuration and external scripts. But I guess this answer is the most correct for the information I provided.